# Varnish: conditionally purge cache to ensure resource up to date

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Assume I have a "resource" - `http://localhost/doc`, I expect it to be cached by Varnish **all the time** since it is visited frequently, **except** someone updated it through POST, after the POST update finished, all the further requests should retrieve the latest version of "doc".

My thoughts is wrap this logic inside my backend server, since POST request will by default pass through Varnish without caching, and in my backend server I can:

1. Exec a Command: `varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 purge req.url == "/doc"`
2. Fire an HTTP purge request: `curl -X PURGE http://localhost/doc`

However, it need I config VCL to honor "`Cache-Control`" header!
My VCL is like below but not work:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
        purge;
    }
    return (deliver);
}
acl purgers { "127.0.0.1"; }

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purgers) {
            error 405 "Method not allowed";
        }
        return (lookup);
    }
}
sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        #purge;
        purge("req.url ~ " req.url); 
        error 200 "Purged";
    }
}
sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") { 
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged";
    }
}
sub vcl_pass {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        error 502 "PURGE on a passed object";
    }
}
```

It complaint:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected ';' got '('

(program line 174), at
('input' Line 154 Pos 14)
        purge("req.url ~ " req.url); 
-------------#-----------------------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1

VCL compilation failed
```

- Question1: How to update the VCL to achieve my goal?
- Question2: I
  think this is a very common scenario: cache resource while keeps it
  up to date, then what is the best practise for achieving this using
  Varnish?

Thank you for any response!

Comment: In Varnish 3 purge() was renamed to ban() and purge; was introduced. Please see https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Cache_invalidation.html

Comment: Thank you Ketola, I've actually found it today: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/installation/upgrade.html?highlight=purge however, I am still waiting for question 2 to be answered:)

Answer (score 0):

Your application server can make a request to purge a url when the doc gets updated. It needs to send a PURGE request rather than a GET request for the doc.

Alternatively you could issue a ban on the url when you get a POST to that url when you receive it.